# Canonical bundle and Möbius bundle

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

I have to prove that the canonical bundle over $\mathbb{R}P^1$ is isomorphic to Möbius bundle. We define the caninical bundle as $\xi=\{E^{\perp},p,S^1 \}$ where $E^\perp:=\{(l,v) \in \mathbb{R}P^{1} \times \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \ v \perp l \}$ and $p(l,v)=v$ and the Moebius bundle $\eta:=\{E,q,S^1\}$ where $E:=\frac{[0,1] \times \mathbb{R}}{(0,x)\sim(1,-x)}$. How can I prove this bundles-isomorphism?

Comment: One way, assuming you already know that there are only two real-line bundles over $S^1$, is to show that $E^\perp$ is nonorientable, or equivalently, to show that it is a nontrivial bundle by demonstrating that every section of the bundle must vanish at some point.

Comment: Cross Posted on MO (by different people?) http://mathoverflow.net/questions/128840/isomorphism-vector-bundles-closed

Comment: @ChrisGerig How can I do this?

Comment: @ArthurStuart: a section of the canonical bundle over $\mathbb{R} P^1$ is a continuous choice of a point on each line through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is a certain kind of map from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  You have to show that any such map must pass through the origin.